# One-hot encoding in pytorch/torchtext

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, torchtext

I have a `Bucketiterator` from `torchtext` that I feed to a model in `pytorch`. An example of how the iterator is constructed:

```
train_iter, val_iter = BucketIterator.splits((train,val),
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             sort_within_batch = True, 
                                             device = device, 
                                             shuffle=True, 
                                             sort_key=lambda x: (len(x.src), len(x.trg)))
```

The data is then fed to a model like this, where I use the `nn.Embedding` layer.

```
class encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout):
        super().__init__()

        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.emb_dim = emb_dim
        self.hid_dim = hid_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.dropout = dropout

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_dim, emb_dim)

        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout = dropout)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, src):

        #src = [src sent len, batch size]

        embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(src))

        #embedded = [src sent len, batch size, emb dim]
        hidden_enc = []
        outputs, hidden = self.rnn(embedded[0,:,:].unsqueeze(0))
        for i in range(1,len(embedded[:,1,1])):
            outputs, hidden = self.rnn(embedded[i,:,:].unsqueeze(0),hidden)
            hidden_cpu = []
            for k in range(len(hidden)):
                hidden_cpu.append(hidden[k])
                hidden_cpu[k] = hidden[k].cpu()
            hidden_enc.append(tuple(hidden_cpu))



        #outputs, hidden = self.rnn(embedded)

        #outputs = [src sent len, batch size, hid dim * n directions]
        #hidden = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hid dim]
        #cell = [n layers * n directions, batch size, hid dim]
        None
        #outputs are always from the top hidden layer

        return hidden, hidden_enc
```

But what if I wanted the embedding to be one-hot encoded? I work on formal languages and it would be nice to preserve orthogonality between tokens. It doesn't seem like `pytorch` or `torchtext` has any functionality for doing this.

Comment: PyTorch doesn't have it built in, but would this be helpful: https://gist.github.com/jacobkimmel/4ccdc682a45662e514997f724297f39f

Comment: PyTorch has [`torch.nn.functional.one_hot(...)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.functional.html#one-hot), but if I understood correctly, you want your embedding to have the same properties of a one_hot vector; not just map N inputs to N one_hot vectors, but map M >> N to N one_hot vectors? There are several ways to achieve that. Let us know if that's what you want.

Comment: No not yet, I am looking at parenthesis languages and seq2seq models ability to close those parentheses, so I would like to preserve the distance between the tokens, hence one-hot. But I am interested in how to achieve it for M>>N I feel that could be useful down the line?

Comment: But do you understand that the only way to do it (given that you want them to be one-hot encoded) is by collapsing multiple tokens to the same vector (for M > N), don't you? Would that be okay for you?

Comment: Yes, sure, I was thinking that if it was trained like the embedding layer, it might help the network make discrete decisions over larger scale structure than the standard one-hot.

Answer (score 0):

def get_one_hot_torch_tensor(in_tensor):
"""
Function converts a 1d or 2d torch tensor to one-hot encoded
"""

```
n_channels = torch.max(in_tensor)+1  # maximum number of channels
if in_tensor.ndim == 2:
    out_one_hot = torch.zeros((n_channels, in_tensor.shape[0], in_tensor.shape[1]))
    # print(out_one_hot)
    index = np.indices((in_tensor.shape[0], in_tensor.shape[1]))  # create an array of indices
    x, y = index[0], index[1]
    print(x, y)

    out_one_hot[in_tensor, x, y] = 1
    print(out_one_hot)
```

Comment: The input tensor is a single channel 2D tensor where pixel values are classes. The function returns a one-hot encoded tensor where the encoding is channel wise, i.e, for every pixel there are num_classes + 1 channels, the channel corresponding to the pixel value is 1, others are 0.